# Can new Date() case a memory leak in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks, express

In this **first example** I am updating an existing MongoDB document. Will `date: new Date()`
 cause a memory leak? If no, Why? *I read somewhere that whenever you allocate a new object using **new** keyword, you must deallocate it yourself.*

```
var update = {
  $inc: { wins: 1 },
  $push: { pastMatches: { date: new Date, winner: winner, loser: loser } }
};
Character.update({ characterId: winner }, update);
```

In this **second example**, I am using the following Express.js middleware for error logging. Will this code cause a memory leak if you call it each time you have an error in the app routes? Will **new Date()** get garbage collected or not?

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  console.error(new Date, err);
  res.send(500);
});
```

Thanks! I am trying to track down a memory leak in my application and these are a few examples that stood out to me.

Comment: JavaScript is a garbage-collection runtime, so no, you don't have to deallocate objects yourself. However, you have to avoid "pinning" them.  It's not impossible that the console mechanism itself would sit on references passed like that. How many errors are you triggering?  A `Date` instance shouldn't be very big.

Comment: _I read somewhere that whenever you allocate a new object using new keyword, you must deallocate it yourself._ -> are you sure it was about JavaScript and not C++?

Comment: Why do those particular lines of code stand-out as candidates? If you're using all of the moving parts you suggest, there are tens of thousands of other lines of code that are executing.

Comment: Also -- what is the nature of the memory leak? How do you reproduce it?

Comment: @WiredPrairie I cannot reproduce the memory leak. My application crashes every so often. I use **OpenShift Metrics** to monitor CPU and Memory usage. Memory indeed spikes up. I get the following output after my application crashes: `(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.`

Comment: @Pointy @WiredPrairie I am also using a lot of streams, particularly   with `gridfs-stream`, for saving downloaded images to MongoDB. Could that be the problem?

Comment: I suppose it's possible there's a bug somewhere in the gridfs-stream implementation but without a lot deeper analysis of the application, I wouldn't want to speculate. You're going to need to write some tests against the various aspects of your application to help you identify the root causes of the crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of those look totally benign to me. Look for objects used as caches, arrays being constantly appended to, etc. You should also be sure that you really have a memory leak and not just v8 using a lot of memory. Try reproducing steady memory growth with smaller and more specific usage of your web app to narrow it down.